# what is the fgets() equivalent in Python

Tags: python, c

I am currently working with file handling in Python.
I have problem in copying the string value of the file.

I wanted to copy the string from file and store it to a variable, just like in C

example: this is how we do in C

```
FILE *fptr = fopen("read.txt", "r");
fgets(charVar, 100, fptr);
```

where we store the string file to charVar.
So is there a fgets() function equivalent to python?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the limit argument to `readline` for a file object which would have similar behavior of stopping on a max character or a newline. Example text file:

```
01234567890123456789
01234567890123456789
```

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    while data := f.readline(8):
        print("line:", data)
```

Outputs:

```
line: 01234567
line: 89012345
line: 6789

line: 01234567
line: 89012345
line: 6789
```